# Binary search problem (i have more than log2(n) iterations)

Tags: binary-search

problem conditions:
This is an interactive task.

Someone made a wish for an integer x (1 ≤ x ≤ n). Your program must guess this number in interaction with the testing system. In total, you can do two different types of actions:

? y (1 ≤ y ≤ n) — ask to compare the hidden number with the number y. The response will either contain the string “>=”, indicating that x ≥ y, or the string “<”, indicating that x < y.
! y (1 ≤ y ≤ n) — report y as the answer. After that, your program should end.
Interaction protocol

First, the input to your program is an integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 109). After that, the testing system is ready to respond to your program's requests.

Output queries one per line according to the conditions. After each request of the format “? y” read the line with the answer to it. The total number of requests of this type cannot exceed the binary logarithm of the number n, rounded up. If the number of requests is exceeded, the result of the check will be an error “Wrong answer".

Interaction Example

16

? 9

<

? 5

'>='

? 7

<

? 6

'>='

! 6

i putted '>=' in quotes because of stackoverflow syntaxis

my code is working ok but when im trying to find a number thats equals n i have more than log2(n) iterations and thats the problem. here's code:

```
n = int(input())
low = 1
high = n
ymem = None
while low <= high:
    mid = (low + high) // 2
    print('?', mid)
    y = str(input())
    if y == '<':
        high = mid - 1
    else:
        low = mid + 1
    ymem = y
if ymem == '>=':
    print('!', mid)
elif ymem == '<':
    print('!', mid - 1)
```